# Subtitles for DRM content

Tags: azure-media-services

I use Azure Media Player v2.3.2. There are existing encoded videos that work great to which I should include subtitles (VTT). Videos are DRM protected. I cannot find any documentation discussing the topic, just few (too) simple samples.

1. Should I use one separate shared container holding ALL subtitles of ALL media assets, or should I create one separate asset for subtitles of each media asset?
2. If I should create separate assets for each video, how can the media player know what subtitle asset belongs to the media asset as they're separete?
3. If I should create one shared asset for all subtitles of all media files, is there any limitations on how many subtitles I can have in this asset?
4. How does the media player know what all subtitles are available in the subtitle asset, to begin with?
5. How should I secure this subtitle asset to prevent downloading subtitles from it?

Answer (score 1):

Jussi,
Thanks for asking. It is a difficult topic to find a lot of information on in our docs and samples.

1. We recommend keeping all the VTT files in the same Asset.  We recently introduced a new "Tracks" API on Asset as well to make it easier to "late-bind" caption and audio tracks to an Asset.  Docs are still being worked on, but I have a sample in Typescript up here that shows how to add a VTT track to an existing asset - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/media-services-v3-node-tutorials/blob/main/Assets/add-WebVTT-tracks.ts
   Once you add a track of VTT, AMS will convert that to an IMSC text track that AMP and other players can understand. You have to set the language code correctly, and then tell AMP which language code IMSC1 tracks to display
2. Don't create separate assets. Not required
3. I don't believe we set a limit on Tracks at all... But I need to check with dev.
4. AMP only knows what subtitles are there if you configure it to find them. The AMP API has a setting on it to describe which IMSC1 to load. You can do this in the imsc1caption settings. For example, if you add an 'en-us' VTT file with the tracks API, you have to set the AMP player up to look for the 'en-us' IMSC1 file.  It will read that from the DASH manifest.
   https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/docs/index.html#amp.player.imsc1captionssettings

For other 3rd party players, they will read the caption track information from the DASH or HLS manifest file.  We decorate them in the manifest appropriately according to those specifications so that the players can parse and load them. Each player differs a bit in support, and there are some known issues across players.

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm: A) I have million videos, each in dedicated assets (one asset per video). I should create one additional asset for the subtitles, and have VTTs of those million videos in that one asset?
B) What still puzzles me is if I add track via API, I define language and other properties. But if I add it via Azure Portal Asset view, I just upload the VTT file without any additional properties, such as language. Will those not work if I use the Azure Portal upload?

Comment: A) Not quite what I said. You have 1 million videos.  That is a million assets.  You just need to upload the correct VTT files into those million assets and use the tracks API to attach the VTT to them.

Comment: B) Ignore the Portal for now... it's not updated yet to work with the new tracks API.  Just pretend like that does not exist, as how would you do that 1 million times anyways...

Comment: A) How can I have the subtitle in the same asset as the video is DRM-protected? "This approach works for clear content but not for protected (DRM) content. For protected content, you should use a separate container (or asset) for the subtitles files." https://stackoverflow.com/a/65406664/1441451

Comment: None of the DRM systems support encryption of the captions.  If you need to encrypt the captions you would need to look at using Envelope encryption with just AES-128.  That's the only way to do it.   PlayReady and Widevine both use Common Encryption in our service which does not encrypt the captions or subtitles.   If you add the track to the existing asset with DRM, the captions will work, but be in the clear.

Comment: And even if I try to update the track's playerVisibility via API, it remains "Hidden".

Comment: Good question! Let me grab someone on the team and add them here

Comment: @JussiPalo can you ping us at amshelp@microsoft.com - the dev team wants to check on your account and VTT files.  There may be something failing in conversion. Just refer to this stack thread and we can support you.